# Cos'è la "memoria condivisa"?

Tags: word-meaning

In occasione del 28 maggio, sono comparsi volantini e manifesti con lo slogan "**nessuna memoria condivisa**". Cosa significa, esattamente, *memoria condivisa*, nel suo significato sociologico [in opposizione a quello informatico]? Memoria di cosa, e soprattutto, condivisa da chi?
Visto l'utilizzo, sospetto che questa sia un'espressione a sé stante, ma non ho trovato alcuna spiegazione del suo significato né su [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22memoria%20condivisa%22) né su [treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/memoria-condivisa/).

Comment: [Questo](http://www.presentepassato.it/150_anni/2_Memoria/prob_mem11-margalit_memoria_mito.htm) potrebbe essere utile a spiegare la nozione di 'memoria condivisa'? Più o meno quello che gli americani chiamano 'mito fondante' di una comunità, che non è importante per la sua effettiva realtà storica ma per i significati che il mito serve a mantenere vivi nella comunità. [Alcuni storici](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13545719908454992?journalCode=rmis20#.U-I6p0YcRMs) dicono che no, gli italiani non hanno miti fondanti … sulla Strage di Piazza della Loggia meno che meno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mettendo insieme gli spunti forniti da *uomoinverde* e *Elberich Schneider*, azzardo un'interpretazione.

Per *'memoria condivisa'* si intende un insieme di racconti storici o mitici che mantengono vivi in una data comunità senso d'identità, valori, ideali, aspirazioni, usanze, contribuendo insieme ad altri fattori a far da collante tra gli aderenti a quella comunità stessa. Tali racconti debbono essere tali da suscitare emozioni e valutazioni simili e concordi tra i più, o almeno tra chi conta di più, ma senza suscitare eccessivi contrasti, senza scatenare eccessive conflittualità nella
comunità più ampia. Forse questa è la differenza rispetto alla *'memoria collettiva'* citata da *uomoinverde* che invece mi sembra possa contenere racconti molto discordi tra di loro, e quindi non abbia la funzione di collante: in questo caso la *'memoria condivisa'* potrebbe considerarsi un sottoinsieme della *'memoria collettiva'*? Da notare però che [qui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_memory) si dice che la memoria collettiva è anche condivisa, nel senso di "shared", e si mette in collegamento con altri concetti quali *'intelligenza collettiva'*, *'coscienza collettiva'*, *'conoscenza distribuita'*: secondo me è "shared" solo nel senso che è generata collettivamente e quindi a disposizione di tutti, ma non tale da generare le stesse risposte emotive come suggerito invece dall'aggettivo italiano "condiviso" che mi sembra più forte dell'inglese "shared".

Quindi, per fare un esempio, i fatti relativi ad alcune stragi italiane, tra i quali la Strage di Portella della Ginestra (1947), la Strage di Piazza Fontana (1969), la Strage di Piazza della Loggia (1974), la Strage della stazione di Bologna (1980), le Stragi di Capaci e Via D'Amelio (1993), appartenengono tutti alla memoria collettiva italiana, tutti li ricordano; ma i racconti sono discordi, non è una memoria condivisa, le ricorrenze vengono vissute con emozioni contrapposte e tali non da rafforzare il senso d'identità nazionale quanto piuttosto tali da scatenare conflittualità aperte e apparentemente insanabili.

Per come lo capisco io, il concetto di *'memoria condivisa'* è associato a quello di *'mito fondante'* (o *fondativo*).

[Qui](http://www.deportati.it/static/upl/pr/present_cereda.pdf) ho trovato alcune opinioni interessanti, ne cito un paio:

> La memoria è soggettiva, non può essere condivisa; può essere confrontata, ma non condivisa. Ciò che si può cercare di condividere non è una memoria, ma una storia (Walter Barberis)
>
> Memoria collettiva […] non equivale necessariamente a memoria condivisa […]: perché l‟una rimanda ad un unico passato, cui nessuno di noi può sottrarsi e che coincide appunto con la nostra storia; mentre l‟altra sembra presumere un‟operazione più o meno forzosa di azzeramento delle identità e di occultamento delle differenze. Il rischio di una memoria condivisa è una "smemoratezza parteggiata", la comunione della dimenticanza. (Sergio Luzzatto)

E [qui](http://www.presentepassato.it/150_anni/2_Memoria/00_memoria_intervento_fabio.htm) c'è invece un discorso più ampio in cui si discute di memoria collettiva, condivisa, comune, pubblica, uso pubblico della storia, e altro. Ma ci stiamo allontanando dalla lingua italiana per addentrarci nei meandri insidiosi della filosofia, della storia, della sociologia e della politica.

Comment: Risposta perfetta! Questa è l'unica a interpretare la locuzione nel suo contesto originario - in modo più che soddisfacente, tra l'altro - anziché limitarsi a fornirne una triviale interpretazione letterale (con tutto il rispetto per chi, comunque, ci ha provato). *Good job*!

Comment: @Giulio, grazie del commento. In realtà ho preso molto dalle risposte di _uomoinverde_ e _Elberich Schneider_. Il primo mi ha chiarito che la memoria condivisa ha delle proprietà simili a quelle della memoria collettiva (_'free-riding', 'social loafing', 'collaborative inhibition', 'cross-cueing', 'transactive memory'_); il secondo ha evidenziato il ruolo dell'_empatia_ nella formazione della memoria condivisa come _'costrutto sociale'_. La locuzione sembra essere in fase di elaborazione culturale in Italia, dove sono in corso dei dibattiti per chiarirne il significato.

Answer (score 3):

Credo che il concetto di memoria *condivisa* possa essere considerato equivalente a quello di memoria *collettiva*. Quindi la memoria condivisa è quell'insieme di eventi storici, ricordi e ricorrenze che è posseduto da un gruppo generico di individui, sia esso una setta, un partito, una popolazione. La [pagina](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_collettiva) di Wikipedia relativa alla memoria collettiva sembra esporre un concetto molto simile a quello contenuto nella [pagina](http://www.presentepassato.it/150_anni/2_Memoria/prob_mem11-margalit_memoria_mito.htm) riportata da @randomatlabuser.

Answer (score 1):

Con la locuzione 'memoria condivisa' si intende l'insieme degli eventi che due o più persone ricordano con la medesima empatia.

Comment: Questa è l'interpretazione letterale della locuzione, che si può ottenere in modo triviale; ma già nella domanda iniziale avevo espresso il dubbio, confermato poi da randomatlabuser e uomoinverde, che quest'espressione non vada presa alla lettera, ma piuttosto che abbia un significato più particolare legato anche al contesto (gli anni Settanta e la strategia della tensione in Italia).

Comment: Edit: per "contesto" è più corretto dire che mi riferisco alla "rievocazione dello stragismo neofascista degli anni Settanta", piuttosto che degli anni Settanta in sé.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: Che c'è di triviale nell'osservazione di Elberich? (Non è che intendevi “banale”, per caso?)

Comment: @DaG: considero le due parole intercambiabili, e il Treccani - http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/triviale/ - sembra confermare la mia impressione. Puoi indicarmi l'eventuale sfumatura di significato per cui "banale" è più appropriato?

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: Il Treccani parla correttamente (guarda anche la parte etimologica) di un calco recente dall'inglese, usato soprattutto in certi ambiti. Se dici “triviale” sembra che tu stia accusando Elberich di volgarità o almeno di dozzinalità.

Comment: @Giulio, l'empatia è di per sé legata al contesto poiché correlata alle relative emozioni che, se affini, creano quella condivisione suscettibile di diventare memoria.